# Python - Passing in email address from variable into a Python function

Tags: python, email, variables

I am working on building a Python function that emails a simple statement.  I am trying to have the username and email address fetched from the respective variables and passed into the function. I am able to have the username passed but unable to pass the email address as part of the function.

Could anyone guide as to how to pass in email address from the variable  (mail) to "**to**" field. The below code when triggered sends mail to the email mentioned and also an unknown email address.

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

user = ['Steve','Austin']
mail = ['user1@mail.com','user2@mail.com']


def name(user,mail):
    # Email recipients
    sender_email = 'mail@mail.com'
    sender_password = '123456'
    server = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
    to = "%(mail)s"    <-- Holds the email address of the receiver

# Email structure and content
    text = """"""
    html = """Report Generated for - """ + user +"""
    message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html, 'html')])

    message.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
    message['Subject'] = "Test Mail for " + str(user)
    message['From'] = sender_email
    message['To'] = to
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(sender_email, sender_password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, to, message.as_string())
    server.quit()

name('Steve','user1@mail.com')
name('Austin','user2@mail.com')
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @Chillie, I am using version 3.6.5 with Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the line where you assign value to variable `to` like this:

```
to = "%(mail)s" % locals()
```

or like this:

```
to = "%(mail)s" % {'mail': mail}
```

or simply like this:

```
to = mail
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. May be I did not list my problem correctly. Referring to my initial message, first mail should be sent to Steve to the mail ID user1@mail.com and the second mail should be sent to Austin to user2@mail.com

When I tried the above, I found the first mail went only to first mail ID (user1@mail.com) but the second mail went to both mail IDs. Is there any way we could limit the second mail sent only to the second mail ID. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this line:

```
mail = ['user1@mail.com','user2@mail.com']
```

You are eventually looking to pass in a list of email addresses.  If that is the case, you could just eliminate this line:

```
to = "%(mail)s"
```

And change this line:

```
message['To'] = to
```

to:

```
message['To'] = ", ".join(mail)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. May be I did not list my problem correctly. Referring to my initial message, first mail should be sent to Steve to the mail ID user1@mail.com and the second mail should be sent to Austin to user2@mail.com When I tried the above, I found the first mail went only to first mail ID (user1@mail.com) but the second mail went to both mail IDs. Is there any way we could limit the second mail sent only to the second mail ID. Thanks